# What C# class objects acquire unmanaged resources? Is there a list?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, unmanaged, textreader

I was working on serializing and deserializing a class object using XML when I came across this blog post that shows how to do it on Windows Phone 7 using the isolated storage area.  Windows Phone 7 is the platform I am developing for:

In [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2010/08/31/windows-phone-7-xml-isolatedstorage-example.aspx), the only object he explicitly calls **Dispose()** on is the TextReader object.  I looked up the TextReader object on MSDN and found that [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxw7zx80.aspx) said this:

> Releases the unmanaged resources used by the TextReader and optionally releases the managed resources.

So I assume the reason he does this is to release immediately the unmanaged resources acquired by the TextReader object.  It would not have occurred to me to do this if it weren't for his blog post.  Obviously I don't want to start calling Dispose() on every object in sight, so what is a good rule of thumb for at least investigating when a particular object should have Dispose() called on it or not?  Are there some guidelines for this or a list somewhere, at least of the popular .NET objects that require this special handling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Obviously I don't want to start calling Dispose() on every object in

Wrong.

In general, any object that implements `IDisposable` should be disposed as soon as you're finished with it, typically using the `using` statement.

Most objects that do not have unmanaged resources do not implement `IDisposable` (and do not have `Dispose()` methods), so you have nothing to worry about.

The only exceptions are base classes that implement `IDisposable` in case some derived implementations have something to dispose (eg, `IEnumerator`, `Component`, or `TextReader`).
However, it is not always obvious which concrete implementations need to be disposed (and it may change at any time), so you should always dispose them anyway.

Comment: Then that is the guideline is it?  Check to see an object implements IDisposable?  Can I assume that if an object has Dispose() in Intellisense I should call it?  Or do a lot of objects inherit that call when it is vestigal.  That is, just a shell for the call that does not do anything?

Comment: Even if its just "vestigial", you have no way of knowing that unless you inspect the source code. Implementing `IDisposable` is a contract with the caller that they will ensure the object gets disposed when they are finished with it. The implementation details might change, but you can't make those assumptions.

Comment: To be safe, if it has a Dispose method, call it. When you get more comfortable with it, you can learn which things don't 'really' need to be disposed. E.g., don't bother disposing Task objects. It's not important to dispose of in-memory IO objects (like StringWriter, for instance). The documentation of the particular class/method should specify all this. But it's okay to err on the side of caution and dispose everything.

Comment: @CodyGray - Thanks.  Is there any historical reason C#/.NET just didn't have call Dispose() on IDisposable objects automatically when exiting the current stack context?  Also, thanks for the edits you made, changing the raw links to links with anchor text.

Comment: @Robert Not really sure about the history/rationale behind the decision. To me, the [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) used in C++ (which really has more significance in guaranteeing calls to the destructor than the name would indicate) makes more sense. But I'm sure someone thought this all through, since RAII was already a well-established pattern.

Comment: @Jacob Not sure I agree with that. You're still relying on implementation details that could easily change from one version of the framework to the other. And let's not kid ourselves, no one goes through and checks all their code for each update. We just cross our fingers and make sure it compiles. The point is, there's no real *harm* in calling Dispose().

Comment: @CodyGray particularly for the Task case, there is harm, namely that if you try to do it, you'll probably get it wrong (which can cause bugs in completely separate code), and getting it right requires ugly, ugly code. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx . For the StringWriter example I can see your point but it's kind of braindead obvious that a class like that does not acquire unmanaged resources.

Comment: @RobertOschler: An unfortunate design decision in Java, which was appropriate for Java's intended use, but not for its eventual uses, was to use the same kind of variables and fields to encapsulate the *mutable state* of objects a thing owns, the *identity* of a possibly-shared mutable object, *both* identity and mutable state, or *neither* identity nor mutable state.  Microsoft's .NET framework followed .net's example and did likewise.  The proper paradigm would be to use RAII for mutable objects (which generally have a clear owner), and garbage collection for immutable ones...

Comment: ...(since they generally don't have a clear owner).  Unfortunately, I don't know any framework which really combines the two paradigms.  Too bad, since each handles well things the other does not; the only problematic situation for the combination would be read-only objects that hold resources; such things may not have a clear owner, but should be cleaned up as soon as the last user no longer needs them.  Still, using reference-counting for that and non-counted RIAA for all other mutable or resource-holding objects would be a 99% win.

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously I don't want to start calling Dispose() on every object in sight, so what is a good rule of thumb for at least investigating when a particular object should have Dispose() called on it or not?

This is not a problem. The compiler won't let you call Dispose() on an object that doesn't implement it.

And you *should be* calling Dispose() for every object that *does* implement it (which it will do via the `IDisposable` interface). That is the guideline you should be following. In fact, that's what it *means* when an object implements `IDisposable`: that it has unmanaged resources that need to be released.

It becomes much less of a chore if you'll simply wrap the creation and use of the objects in a `using` statement, e.g.:

```
using (DisposableObject obj = new DisposableObject(...))
{
    obj.DoWork();
} // obj.Dispose() is automatically called here, even if an exception is thrown
```

Comment: Thanks!  That side-effect of using is just what I'm looking for.

Comment: +1. @RobertOschler, Just wondering what is goal of `using` from your point of view than? (if `Dispose` is side effect, something should be real goal...)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I thought "using" was for aliasing and thereby simplifying object chains in code?  I didn't know it also worked as a scope boundary for object lifetimes.

Comment: @RobertOschler, I see. Thanks... I did not realize that "you need to write code this way" can lead to such assumption. I'll keep it in mind whenever I need to reply about using in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you do have to dispose of objects which implement IDisposable.

The standard way of doing that as opposed to directly calling the Dispose() is:

```
using(AnyIDisposable obj = ...)
{
    // work with obj here
}
//The Dispose() method is already called here
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if i'm wrong.
As far a i read/understood, all clases of the .NET Framework are managed (to the view of the programmer, although underderlaying they might use unmanaged code), so theoretically you dont need to call Dispose() or using, because the gc will take care. But sometimes it's very recommended to use them, see [IDisposable Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908463/idisposable-interface) and
[Which managed classes in .NET Framework allocate (or use) unmanaged memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515438/which-managed-classes-in-net-framework-allocate-or-use-unmanaged-Memory) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kimhamil/archive/2008/11/05/when-to-call-dispose.aspx

EDIT: (you are right noob) For clarification i'll add Nayan answer from [IDisposable Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908463/idisposable-interface)

It recommended to call dispose or using, when:

> 1.You class has many objects and there are of lots of cross references. Even though its all managed, GC may not be able to reclaim
> the memory due to alive references. You get a chance (other than
> writing a finalizer) to untangle the references and break up the links
> the way you attached them. Hence, you are helping the GC to reclaim
> the memory.
>
> 2.You have some streams open which are alive till the object of the class dies. Even though such implementations of files/network etc are
> managed, they go deep down to handles in Win32 mode. Hence, you get a
> chance to write a Dispose method where you can close the streams. The
> same is true for GDI objects, and some more.
>
> 3.You are writing a class which uses unmanaged resources, and you want to ship your assembly to third parties. You better use disposable
> pattern to make sure you are able to free the handles to avoid the
> leakage.
>
> 4.Your class implements lots of event handlers and hooks them up to events. The objects of classes which
> expose the events, like Form etc., will not be freed up by GC since
> the implementations local to your class (maybe) are still hooked into
> those events. You can unhook those event handlers in Dispose; again
> helping GC.

Comment: I think the best summary of `IDisposable` is "your class has asked outside entities to do things on its behalf, to the possible detriment of other entities, and needs to let the former entities know when their services are no longer required".  All four of the items from the link satisfy that criterion (though #1 only in the case where many items hold mutual references; the job of `Dispose` is to clear out references *to* the object being Disposed) and many more do besides.